# Is there an easy way to use Vim text-objects on camel case words?

Tags: vim

Often I'll be doing a quick edit to a camel case word in some code and wish I could use something like text-objects to select one part of the camel case word.

For example, given this snippet:

```
class TextObject:
    pass
```

If my cursor is on the 'x' in TextObject, I would like to quickly select/operate on the word 'Text'.  If my cursor is on the 'j', I would like to manipulate the word 'Object'.

Vim text-objects allow me to quickly manipulate the entire word TextObject (e.g 'caw'), but I've noticed that I quite often want to manipulate only a single word in a camel case string like this.

Any pointers?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is exactly what the [CamelCaseMotion](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1905) script is for.  I use it all the time.

Comment: Thanks, guess I was too hung up on there possibly being a built-in solution to think of looking for a script!